# Copying code from a textarea into function

Tags: javascript

I have a page that has a textarea called Program. A user can put Javascript code in the Program window, and my page will execute this Javascript code and place the result in an output window.

One way I've thought of accomplishing this is to essentially copy and paste the Program textarea into an empty function, and then call that function. I'm fairly new to Javascript so I don't know if something like this is possible. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
myFunction = new Function(mytextarea.value);
```

But please, put it in an iframe.

```
myIframe.srcdoc = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script>"+mytextarea.value+"</script></head><body>You could put stuff here.</body></html>";
```

Comment: What's the reason for wanting it in an iframe?

Comment: You don't want the user to mess up the page they're working in.

Comment: How would I then call this function on for example a button click? I've tried, <button type="button" onclick="myFunction>Go</button> but I am getting a "myFunction is not defined error".